Performance issues with SetConsoleCursorPosition and real-time console rendering in C++
Problem Description:
I'm developing a game in the Windows console using C++ and facing performance issues with rendering. The rendering pipeline involves multiple calls to SetConsoleCursorPosition and std::cout to display a precomputed buffer. However, the frame rendering time is inconsistent:

Buffer generation is relatively fast, taking ~2000 microseconds per frame.

Cursor repositioning using SetConsoleCursorPosition is a bottleneck, sometimes taking up to 20–25 milliseconds.

Outputting the buffer with std::cout is reasonably efficient but still contributes to delays when combined with other steps.


Code Example:
Here’s my current rendering iteration code:
void Renderer::render() {
    auto frameStart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto frameEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    // Frame generation
    frameStart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int invY = 0; invY < RENDERER_HEIGHT; invY++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < RENDERER_WIDTH; x++) {
            buffer[(invY) * (2 * RENDERER_WIDTH + 1) + 2 * x] = ' ';
            for (auto& renderable : toRender) {
                if (renderable->render(x, RENDERER_HEIGHT - invY - 1) != ' ') {
                    buffer[(invY) * (2 * RENDERER_WIDTH + 1) + 2 * x] = renderable->render(x, RENDERER_HEIGHT - invY - 1);
                }
            }
            buffer[(invY) * (2 * RENDERER_WIDTH + 1) + 2 * x + 1] = ' ';
        }
        buffer[(invY) * (2 * RENDERER_WIDTH + 1) + 2 * RENDERER_WIDTH] = '\n';
    }
    buffer[(2 * RENDERER_WIDTH + 1) * RENDERER_HEIGHT] = '\0';
    frameEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    Logger::get()->log("Renderer frame generation time: " + 
        std::to_string(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(frameEnd - frameStart).count()));

    // Cursor repositioning
    frameStart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, {0, 0});
    frameEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    Logger::get()->log("SetConsoleCursorPosition time: " + 
        std::to_string(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(frameEnd - frameStart).count()));

    // Buffer output
    frameStart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << buffer << debugBuffer;
    frameEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    Logger::get()->log("Renderer output time: " + 
        std::to_string(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(frameEnd - frameStart).count()));
}

Observations:

Cursor repositioning with SetConsoleCursorPosition is the main bottleneck, with execution times often spiking to tens of milliseconds.

The entire screen buffer is written at once using std::cout, which is generally efficient but doesn't eliminate the delays caused by cursor repositioning.

Overall frame times vary unpredictably, which impacts real-time rendering.

SetConsoleCursorPosition, WriteConsoleOutput, ansi escape sequences introduce random latency on their own, regardless of the size of the area being updated.



Attempts to Solve the Problem:

Reduced the number of cursor repositioning calls by consolidating them.

Used a double-buffering technique to minimize flickering using CreateConsoleScreenBuffer and SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer.

Explored alternatives like WriteConsoleOutput for direct manipulation of the console screen buffer.

Used Ansi escape sequences.



Questions:

Are there faster alternatives to SetConsoleCursorPosition for cursor movement?

Are there faster ways to redraw console buffer?

What general techniques can be used to optimize rendering for real-time console applications in C++?



Thank you for your help! Any advice or insights are greatly appreciated.

What exactly is the "double-buffering technique" that you attempted? Does it involve CreateConsoleScreenBuffer and SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer? And what was the result of this attempt?

Try using cout.write(...) instead of cout<<... since you know your buffer size up front. But, using SetConsoleCursorPosition+cout is definitely not the way to go in general. Use WriteConsoleOutput() instead (and only for areas that actually change between frames. Limit how often you actually need to write output). Or, use Ansi escape sequences, if your console supports that. Or, use a 3rd party solution like ncurses.

@AndreasWenzel Yes, it does involve those. I created two buffers and used SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer to switch to the buffer I filled during the current tick. However, I experienced the same issue with time inconsistency during the WriteConsoleOutput stage before calling SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer

@RemyLebeau It seems that calling WriteConsoleOutput introduces random latency on its own, regardless of the size of the area being updated. Even when I try to redraw just two symbols in two separate 1x1 areas using two WriteConsoleOutput calls, there is occasionally ~15ms of latency. I also tried using escape sequences, but they cause the same issue.

Related: Why is console animation so slow on Windows? (And is there a way to improve speed?)
